Android Studio Pepper Emulator Insufficient Storage
I need help with the Pepper Emulator (part Pepper robot framework / SDK).
My Pepper emulator in Android Studio (4.2.2, as the emulator does not work with higher versions properly) used to work properly. Lately it started having issues with the storage space. I keep getting this error, no application can be installed anymore:

Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE

I tried the following:

Deleting all apps from the virtual device (nothing on there anymore)
Wiping the device clean in AVD manager (not possible, as the device is not listed there)
Adding android:installLocation="preferExternal" to an apps manifest
Re-Installing the Pepper Plugin
Re-Installing Android Studio from scratch

I also have to say, that the app is not too big and runs on the physical device without any problem. I even tried to run asimple Hello-World - but I get the error as well.
Nothing helped and I am still unable to emulate any app on the virtual device. Did anyone experience this before? I appreciate any help I can get!

I just had the same issue (Windows 11, Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2). What I did to fix it was to find the correct directory of the AVD, change the partition size in a config file AND remove a .img file. This could only be a temporary fix (if some more general insufficient storage SO posts apply here as well), but for me it's currently working (several days now) with no noticeable increase in disk space used.
To fix your problem, you need to do the following:

Locate your AVD (for me it was in AppData\Roaming\Softbank Robotics\RobotSDK\API 7\avd\x86)
Open the config.ini and change disk.dataPartition.size=1000M to something higher, I choose disk.dataPartition.size=6G for 6gb for example.

I also changed sdcard.size to 1000M but I don't think this is necessary


Warning: This will cause you to lose your data on the Pepper emulator, but it is necessary. Delete ram.img in AppData\Roaming\Softbank Robotics\RobotSDK\API 7\avd\x86\snapshots\default_boot. Otherwise the change in the config file will have no effect.

After these changes, you can start the Pepper emulator again (Tools > Pepper SDK > Emulator) and check in the Android settings Storage & USB if it worked. If so, you should now be able to reinstall your app.
